# Rails/ruby: how to retrieve hash key with unknown id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to check if there is `button_attributes` in my parameters. However, there is a random id for the array so I can't verify if `button_attributes`is present or not.

Here is the parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"XsZyQxt0JcV/bD3joM+B0gHMu+GUf1FPcCpWltXGRa9ROs5ei8iG4EgkLz/thogng1cafWVg+5bYAcJulTGdsQ==",
 "letter"=>
  {"campaign_name"=>"",
   "scheduled_at"=>"",
   "filters_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"gender"=>"Select Gender", "creation_date_start"=>"", "creation_date_finish"=>"", "timezone"=>[""], "locale"=>[""], "segment"=>[""]}},
   "nb_recipients"=>"1",
   "core_bot_id"=>"1",
   "messages_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"content"=>"fdsfdfd", "buttons_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"button_text"=>"", "button_url"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "_destroy"=>"false"}},
   "cards_attributes"=>
    {"1514217785795"=>
      {"title"=>"sdffsdfsd",
       "subtitle"=>"fsdfdsdsf",
       "button_share"=>"false",
       "buttons_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"button_text"=>"test", "button_url"=>"http://www.sddssd.fr", "_destroy"=>"false"}},
       "remote_image_url"=>"",
       "_destroy"=>"false"}}},
 "time"=>"now",
 "commit"=>"Save Draft"}
```

What I would need is `params[:letter]['cards_attributes']['1514217785795']['buttons_attributes']` but I can't know "1514217785795".

Any idea how to verify is there are buttons_attributes in my params?

Comment: You'd better include some `button_attributes` in your example data.

Comment: As Stefan pointed out, there *is no such key in your entire data structure*, so there is no way to find it. If you do a simple text search for `button_attributes`, you will find that the only hits are in the textual description of your question, but it *does not appear* in the code you posted. It is simply not there, ergo, there is no way to find it, since it doesn't exist.

Comment: Also, your hash doesn't have `:letter` as key.

Comment: This is a pure-Ruby question so it should not have a Rails tag. When giving an example please pare it down to its essentials. For example,  many of the nested key-value pairs are not relevant to the question, so should be removed. Similarly, there was no need to make the value of `"authenticity_token"` an 88-character string when, say, "XsZ" would have sufficed.

Comment: @CarySwoveland How do you know it's a pure-Ruby question? I see their inclusion of that tag as indication that they're using this in Rails and thus can take advantage of the functionality that Rails adds to Ruby. And that answers are therefore very welcome to take advantage of that added functionality. And for that I think including the Rails tag is beneficial and appropriate. No?

Comment: @Stefan, yes, the Rails tag should stay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to use [`Hash#values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-values) to retrieve *values* for the hash with an unknown *key*.

```
input["letter"]["cards_attributes"].
  values.   # ⇐ HERE
  map { |hash| hash["buttons_attributes"] }.
  compact   # to eliminate those having no such entry
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for.